# If $x^4 +x^2 +1$ is reducible then why not $x^2 +3x-1?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

which of the  following polynomial  are irreducible ?

$1.$$x^4  +x^2  +1$  over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

$2.$$x^2  +3x -1 $ over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {13}]$

$3.$ None  of these

My attempt : I think none of these

For option $1$: $f(0)\neq 0$, $f(1)\neq 0 $but $( x^4 +x^2 +1)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+1)$

For option $2$ :  $f(\sqrt{13})\neq 0$ ,$f(-\sqrt{13}) \neq  0$ but $x^2  +3x -1=( x-\frac{-3 + \sqrt{13}}{2}) (x+\frac{-3 + \sqrt{13}}{2})$

Therefore  $x^4 +x^2  +1$  is reducible similarly $x^2 +3x-1$  is reducible

Edit : Roots of $x^2 +x +1 \notin \mathbb{Z_2}$ similarly  root  of $( x-\frac{-3 + \sqrt{13}}{2}) \notin \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$

**My question** :  If  $x^4 +x^2 +1$ is reducible  then   why not $x^2 +3x-1?$

Comment: Everything seems fine to me

Comment: In the second, check if the coefficients of your factorization are in the right ring.

Comment: @owl what is  the meaning of  right ring ?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$. It is a small detail, depending on how you defined "irreducible over". Maybe in your case it means in the polynomials with coefficients in the field of fraction of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$ or maybe with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$.

Comment: Here $a+b\sqrt{13}$. I put $ a=0,b=0$ @owl

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. What I mean is that $\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\notin\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$. So, check if your definition of "irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$" means that the polynomials is an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}][x]$ or if it means that it is an irreducible element of $R[x]$, where $R$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$.

Comment: Please clarify your post. Since $(-3+\sqrt{13})/2\not\in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{13}]$, option $2$ is correct, except for another definition of irreducible (as owl said).

Comment: @DietrichBurde  roots of $x^2+x +1 \notin \mathbb{Z_2}$ .Then  why is option  $1$ reducible ?

Comment: okay @DietrichBurde I think option $1$ logic  is same  as  option $2$

Comment: In option 1, you have factored the polynomial into factors whose coefficients lie in $\mathbb{Z}/2$, so it is not irreducible. In option 2, you have factored the polynomial into factors whose coefficients do not lie in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$, so it's not the same situation.

Comment: No, it is not the same logic. In option 1 we really have a factorisation into polynomials of lower degrees (see again the definition of reducible). It is not about the roots there.